# How to open an excel file in R where file format and file extension differ?

Tags: xml, r, excel, package, warnings

I have an excel file where the following warning message appears when I want to open it:

*The file you are trying to open, 'name.ext', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?*

When I click *yes* to open it, everything is fine. However, I want to read this file in R and couldn't manage that R loads the content despite the warning. How can I achieve this?

One example of the files I want to open with R can be downloaded [here.](http://www.comstage.de/Products/ProductDetailsDownloadHistoryExcel.aspx?p=150121874&startDate=__.__.____&endDate=18.11.2015&selectedFields=1) I use MS Office 2016.

Comment: Since you can open the file in excel, why not save it in a normal excel format or as csv?

Comment: That's how I do it so far. However, I have to update the files quite often and I don't want always to open and save the files before I do further processing with R. This takes too much time.

Comment: Have you tried `data.table::fread()`?

Comment: @David I tried it but it gave the error:
embedded nul in string: 'ÿþ<\0?\0x\0m\0l\0 \0v\0e\0r\0s\0i\0o\0n\0=\0"\01\0.\00\0"\0 \0e\0n\0c\0o\0d\0i\0n\0g\0=\0"\0u\0t\0f\0-\01\06\0"\0?\0>\0<\0?\0m\0s\0o\0-\0a\0p\0p\0l\0i\0c\0a\0t\0i\0o\0n\0 \0p\0r\0o\0g

Comment: Hmm ComStage has a pretty weird format (that I do not know). Do you see the data on a website? It might be easier to scrape it from the website...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not displayed on a website.

Comment: I tried to follow this approach here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/schaunwheeler/5825002/raw/3526a15b032c06392740e20b6c9a179add2cee49/xlsxToR.r. But the zip-file cannot be opened (xls is an XML in a zip-folder basically). This is probably what caused the errors in the other approaches as well. What you might want to do is write a VBA-macro that opens all files and then saves them (in the hope of repairing all files) and then open the files in R.

Comment: @David That's what I will try now. I was just hoping that it is possible to put everything in one R script.

Comment: FWIW gnumeric's `ssconvert` can read and convert this to CSV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an XML file with a UTF-16 BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning. You can read it with R:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

xls <- read_html("LU0444605991_434.xls")
values <- html_text(html_nodes(xls, xpath="//cell/data"))
dat <- data.frame(matrix(values[5:length(values)], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(dat) <- c("datum", "nav")
dat$nav <- as.numeric(dat$nav)

head(dat)
##                 datum      nav
## 1 2009-10-05T00:00:00 117.1047
## 2 2009-10-06T00:00:00 117.0746
## 3 2009-10-07T00:00:00 117.0915
## 4 2009-10-08T00:00:00 117.0822
## 5 2009-10-09T00:00:00 116.8312
## 6 2009-10-12T00:00:00 116.9347
```

You can just use the `xml2` package (and `read_xml`) if you really want to bash your head against the wall repeatedly to deal with the crazy XML namespaces in these Microsoft documents.

You'll still need to do date/time conversion and numeric conversion.

Comment: This is just great. Thank you!

Comment: You may have to adjust the code depending on the contents of the returned XLS. This skips the "header/information" rows. You can do something like `cat(stringr::str_wrap(as.character(xls), 80))` to see the structure (adjust `80` depending on your console viewport).