# Importing to R an Excel file saved as web-page

Tags: r, excel

I would like to open an Excel file saved as webpage using R and I keep getting error messages.

The desired steps are:
**1)** Upload the file into RStudio
**2)** Change the format into a data frame / tibble
**3)** Save the file as an xls

The message I get when I open the file in Excel is that the file format (excel webpage format) and extension format (xls) differ. I have tried the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802363/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-r-where-file-format-and-file-extension-differ), but to no avail. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Without see the code you used and the exact error message you received, there is little chance of receiving meaningful help.

Comment: What does this mean: *open an Excel file saved as webpage*? Open an HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect anybody will be able to give you a definitive answer without a link to the actual file. The complication is that many services will write files as .xls or .xlsx without them being valid Excel format. This is done because Excel is so common and some non-technical people feel more confident working with Excel files than a csv file. Now, the files will have been stored in a format that Excel *can deal with* (hence your warning message), but R's libraries are more strict and don't see the actual file type they were expecting, so they fail.

That said, the below steps worked for me when I last encountered this problem. A service was outputting .xls files **which were actually just HTML tables saved with an .xls file extension.**

1) Download the file to work with it locally. You can script this of course, e.g. with `download.file()`, but this step helps eliminate other errors involved in working directly with a webpage or connection.

2) Load the full file with `readHTMLTable()` from the XML package

```
library(XML)
dTemp = readHTMLTable([filename], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This will return a list of dataframes. Your result set will quite likely be the second element or later (see `?readHTMLTable` for an example with explanation). You will probably need to experiment here and explore the list structure as it may have nested lists.

3) Extract the relevant list element, e.g.

```
df = dTemp[2]
```

You also mention writing out the final data frame as an xls file which suggests you want the old-style format. I would suggest the package `WriteXLS` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt Excel is 'saved as a web page'.  I'm pretty sure the file just sits on a server and all you have to do is go fetch it.  Some kind of files (In particular Excel and h5) are binary rather than text files.  This needs an added setting to warn R that it is a binary file and should be handled appropriately.

```
myurl <- "http://127.0.0.1/imaginary/file.xlsx"
download.file(url=myurl, destfile="localcopy.xlsx", mode="wb")
```

or, for use downloader, and ty something like this.

```
myurl <- "http://127.0.0.1/imaginary/file.xlsx"
download(myurl, destfile="localcopy.csv", mode="wb")
```